# Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 3 using length_is

Tags: html, python-3.x, django-1.11

After restructuring some HTML code, I'm running into a unpacking problem. Sometimes the list `menulayer` is length 3, sometimes 2. So I added the if clause `{% if menulayer|length_is:"3"  %}`. See code below.
The problem is I receive an error message for the line `{% for linkname,url in menulayer %}`. This doesn't makle sense, because if there are 3 to unpack, then this part of the `if` statement shouldn't be executed. Where am I going wrong?

```
   {% block navi %}
      {% for menulayer in navicontent %}
    <div id="navigation" class="span-24">
        <ul>
            {% if menulayer|length_is:"3"  %}
                    {% for linkname,url,active in menulayer %}
                        {% if not active %}
                        <li> <a href="{{url}}">{{linkname}}</a> </li>
                        {% else %}
                        <li> <a id="active" href="{{url}}">{{linkname}}</a> </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                        {% for linkname,url in menulayer %}
                            <li> <a href="{{url}}">{{linkname}}</a> </li>
                        {% endfor %}  
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You still can unpack list, and store values to variables.
Example:

```
test_list = [['val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3', 'val_4']]

"""
for a, b in test_list:  # raise "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"
    print(a, b)
"""

for a, b, *_ in test_list:
    print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
val_1 val_2
```

Comment: Thanks but the intention is to test the length inside the html script, not in python